# Agregar motivo de cierre: La pregunta no está formulada en español

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

De vez en cuando aparece una pregunta escrita totalmente en inglés en el sitio.

Considero que sería bastante útil crear como motivo de cierre una opción más que diga algo así como:

> **no está formulada en español**
>
> La pregunta debe ser redactada en español. Si no te sientes a gusto lo suficiente con el idioma, existen otras comunidades donde podrías formularla:
>
> - [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
> - [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
> - [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)
> - [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Entiendo lo que quieres y la idea me parece buena, pero opino que más que crear un motivo de cierre específico para "La pregunta no está formulada en español", lo que hace falta es añadir más opciones a la opción de cierre "Esta pregunta pertenece a otro sitio de la red Stack Exchange".

Ahora mismo sólo se puede seleccionar una opción (meta), lo cual no hace ese motivo muy útil:

[image: Estado actual]

Al menos habría que añadir la opción de StackOverflow en inglés (casi todas las preguntas que he visto estaban en ese idioma) y puede que también la de StackOverflow em Português (creo que junto al inglés es el único idioma que he visto por aquí).

Algo de este estilo (modificando el texto):

[image: Sugerencia de cambio]

Comment: También es una buena idea, pero deberían estar todos los idioma posibles

Comment: +1 a la propuesta, no creo que venga nadie a preguntar en japonés o portugués.

Comment: ¿@CarlosMuñoz y qué sucedería cuando preguntan en un idioma donde no existe SO como francés o klingon (porque existen trolles en este mundo)?

Comment: Mi planteamiento fue el de simplemente cerrar la pregunta no migrarla, así que no hace falta indicar el idioma, pero ya que lo preguntas podría simplemente ser una opción mas del menú que solo cierra y no migre la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde he visto, no son muchos casos que se dan de esta manera. Mi primera idea es apoyar a la idea de @Alvaro en que debería agregarse el sitio stackoverflow.com entre las opciones de migración. Pero si la pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente como portugués u otro que esté disponible en StackOverflow entonces en lugar de agregar todos esos sitios en la migración se podría votar como No Relacionado > Otros y agregar el vínculo al sitio correspondiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto porque, hasta donde he revisado, son casos muy particulares. Y de la misma manera, podría usarse este voto en caso que el autor original (OP) no pueda (o quiera) traducir la pregunta a español.

Comment: Si se puede agregar la opción, ¿porque limitarla a solo Stack Overflow en inglés? Que no se haya dado hasta el momento no impede que pase en un futuro

Comment: Porque es el más popular y porque al parecer los casos se han prestado más para el inglés que para otros idiomas. Ahora, si esta estadística no es correcta, sería mejor colocarla hacia el sitio sobre el que realmente haya más cercanía (quizás sea el portugués)

Comment: ¿Pero qué se gana con limitarla a esta opción? ¿O qué se pierde agregando otros idiomas?

Comment: Ese "límite" que tu llamas es solo una idea y como digo se basa en que es el más popular, no el más cercano a SOes. Ahora, por poner un ejemplo, si vemos que proliferan más preguntas en portugués que en inglés en el sitio, sería mejor que la opción de migración sea hacia SOpt. Por último, si ninguno de esos casos sucede tan a menudo, siempre está la carta abierta del voto *No relacionado > Otro* donde puedes colocar una razón particular para cerrar la pregunta y la gente que concuerde contigo puede votar por esa misma razón.

Answer (score 1):

Según veo yo, ya existe una manera de marcar estas preguntas creadas en otro idioma.

Vean aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Interesante, no había notado esa opción. La utilizaré la próxima vez que vea una pregunta así

Comment: Juan ahora que veo bien solo tenemos habilitada la opción para migrar al meta no a cualquier sitio de la red

Comment: Siguen apereciendo preguntas de este tipo. por ejemplo esta: [Facebook SDK PHP publish in Fan Page](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3454/facebook-sdk-php-publish-in-fan-page). Necesitamos que se habilite esta opcón para todos pronto.

Comment: Por ahora hay que reportarlas y las moveré yo o @Konamiman