# Si el cierre es personalizado, el texto de cierre de la pregunta no debería mencionar que puede no estar escrita en español

Tags: discusión, motivos-de-cierre

Dada una pregunta que se cierra por un motivo personalizado ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/149734/83)), cuando se completa el cierre acaba teniendo la siguiente leyenda explicativa debajo:

> Esta pregunta no parece ser sobre programación en el ámbito definido en el [centro de ayuda](/help) o esta escrita en un idioma diferente al español.

Me sorprende que aparezca la parte final de *esta escrita en un idioma diferente al español* (al que le falta tilde en *está*, por cierto). Me sorprende, digo, porque este es un motivo específico:

> La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.

Por ello, ¿no sería mejor que el motivo de cierre genérico dijera simplemente esto?

> Esta pregunta no parece ser sobre programación en el ámbito definido en el [centro de ayuda](/help).

Answer (score 5):

Muy buen punto, pero si fuese una publicación en otro idioma, exceptuando al inglés, yo usaría un motivo de cierre personalizado.

#### Lo que falta

Actualmente el motivo de cierre dice:

> La pregunta está escrita **en inglés**. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.

- Si estuviese en portugués, ese cierre no aplica.

Al menos hasta que se concrete:

- [La pregunta está escrita en inglés. ¿Pero y si está en otro idioma?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1324/127)

donde tenemos tu muy acertado [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1324/la-pregunta-est%C3%A1-escrita-en-ingl%C3%A9s-pero-y-si-est%C3%A1-en-otro-idioma#comment3486_1324):

> Tal vez lo más fácil sería cambiar el mensaje a **La pregunta no está escrita en español, que es el idioma de este sitio.**

Que también ya se había mencionado algo en

- [Agregar motivo de cierre: La pregunta no está formulada en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420/127)
- o se le dé lugar a varios de los comentarios que pedían que no sea exclusivamente "*en inglés*".

Mientras tanto, sigue habiendo lugar para cerrar una publicación en otro idioma con un motivo personalizado.

#### A favor, pero además...

Me parece una buena propuesta, estoy a favor, pero propongo que primero se incluya a **"otros idiomas"** dentro del motivo de cierre. Es un buen momento para aprovechar y darle una notificación más descriptiva a las preguntas que se cierren con ese motivo (actualmente 1.8 por día, para los últimos 30 días). Por ejemplo,

1. mencionando dónde está el enlace para editarla y traducirla y/o incluyendo el enlace a `/edit` dentro de la descripción del motivo (sabemos que no es algo intuitivo y muchos no saben que pueden editar).
2. el enlace a SO si en realidad quería preguntar en inglés (que siguen siendo la mayor parte de las preguntas cerradas con este motivo).

Comment: @fedorqui, ya man, acepte esta respuesta como solucion

Comment: @MáximaAlekz jajaja. Meta funciona un poco diferente que el sitio principal... Además, tanto a fedorqui como a mí nos encantaría que se acepte la respuesta de un moderador diciendo "*lo modifiqué, ahora este es el texto*" ... (Y por cierto, no le llegan notificaciones a fedorqui acá -para eso sólo en la pregunta cuando nunca comentó en la respuesta)

Comment: Jajaja, sería bueno que el @ llamara a usuarios de forma global, y pues por lo demás, creo que *por algo* nadie más ha intentado responder a la pregunta, porque la tuya es muy completa @Mariano

Comment: @Máx → [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83) y sí, hagamos un `@` a los moderadores para que revisen esto y entonces gustosamente aceptaré una respuesta ;-)